# Door weatherstrip isn't removable, any advice on applying temporary weatherstrip?

Tags: weatherstripping

I have an original-to-house backdoor/sliding screen hybrid ('96) that has old weatherstrip that's created a significant draft, I can feel the breeze at the doorsill. The weatherstrip is attached directly to the door (not the doorframe as expected) and appears to be one solid vinyl strip (sized and shaped for the door) that doesn't appear to be easily removed. The interior of the door frame has a 1/2" 90º lip to prevent water from coming into the house — I cannot add a doorbottom/sweep.

I'm assuming I would need to partially disassemble some component of the door to remove it (plus the headache of finding its replacement). Since it's the middle of winter, I'm not going to do this and instead apply an adhesive weatherstrip. The questions:

- Should I be using a vinyl, foam, or woolpile for a high traffic use?
- Should the new/temporary adhesive-backed weather strip be applied to
  the door frame opposite old strip or directly on top of the old
  weatherstrip?

[image: Door interior where weatherstrip seals to]
[image: Weatherstrip is single piece all the way around door, possibly glued in or hooked into door frame]

Thanks

Comment: Photographs would be helpful. The existing weatherstrip is a solid strip of what? Engineered resin strip, fuzzy stuff, metal spring, ... . Can you cover the entire doorway with heatshrink film for the season or do you need it for access?

Comment: The old weatherstrip appears to be one solid vinyl strip custom built to run the whole height/width of the door. Need to keep access to let the dog out. Will add photos in next few hours

Comment: @HABO added photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a temporary and low cost solution you can add "foam strip" style draft stop / weather seal, and adhere it to the door behind the existing vinyl stop, along the lengths where you have a gap. That's in the space that you opened with your fingers. It will add a little cushion to help the existing seal close the gap.

Since you only have sections that draft, placing it behind the existing stop will provide for a smooth and sealed transition between sections with and without additional foam.

If you add a new strip all around the jamb/stop you might find too much push back when closing the door. And if you apply only sections on the jamb/stop there will likely be a small drafting gap at the transitions between sections, when the door is closed, and it will be unsightly when the door is open.

Comment: This is a great idea, thanks